# animating a background image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am having a view problems with animating a background to give the impression that a window is opening, I have the animation actually animating but it just animates like the images are in sequence. What I am wanting is to give the impression of a movie or animated gif.

You can see my current attempt here,

http://jsfiddle.net/8nj4934w/

I have so far done the following javascript,

```
    $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
       self.animate({ 'background-position-y': '-=500px' });           
    }, 300);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});
```

and the kind of effect I am going for here,

http://www.jeld-wen.com/catalog/exterior-doors

just hover of a door image.

Comment: JSfiddle 404s so we can't see the demo

Comment: your fiddle is not opening

Comment: Remove the /2/ at the end of the URL.

Comment: What exactly is it you are stuck at? Your example fiddle looks good as it is. Do you mean that you don't want the image to disappear at the end?

Answer (score 1):

**Update** (*for jQuery solution handling two way sliding*)

```
function slide(that, increment, limit){
    var self = $(that);
    that.iid && clearInterval( that.iid );

    that.pos = that.pos || 0;
    return setInterval(function () {
        that.pos = that.pos += increment;

        if (that.pos === limit){
            clearInterval(that.iid);
        } else {
            self.css({
                'background-position': '0 '+ that.pos + 'px'
            });
        }
    }, 50);
}

$('a').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    this.iid = slide( this, -500, -11500 );
}).bind('mouseleave', function () {
    this.iid = slide(this, 500, 0);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/g8cypadx/

---

**Original answer**
I would suggest that you use CSS transitions with steps.

```css
a {
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58586640/9100_FRONT_STRIP.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: background-position 1s steps(23);
}
a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -11500px; /* number of steps times the height */
}
```

```html
<a href=""></a>
```

---

If you have to do it through jQuery then you should animate both properties but with 0 duration for the animation, and small delay for the interval

```
$('a').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setInterval(function () {
        self.animate({
            'background-position': '-=0 -=500px'
        }, 0);
    }, 50);
}).bind('mouseleave', function () {
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8nj4934w/2/
(*the problem with this solution is that it will not stop at the end*)

Comment: The CSS3 solution looks elegant, but it breaks easily. Try to hover it many times, gently, and the animation goes crazy. About your jQuery solution, just define a max value and make a test at each frame, so the animation stops at some point.

Comment: @JeremyThille yes, i noticed the CSS stepping goes bad when you hover out during the animation. Looking into it.

Comment: @JeremyThille updated answer with a solution handling two-way slides. (*using custom limits and increments*)

Comment: The jQuery solution now works fine. I can't wait to see the lovely CSS3 approach in action :)